# How can I Start X11VNC automatically on my PC?

Tags: startup, vnc

I have a spare computer that I want to remote desktop control from my Windows 7 PC in my room. I got it to run and I used TightVNC to view and control it.

My real issue is getting it to run automatically when I turn it on. Any way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Could you please be a little more specific in what you are asking? It helps users answer when we know specifications, version of Ubuntu, etc.

Comment: @Flabricorn Ok I'm running a Zorin OS but it is based and almost identical to Ubuntu. I'm not sure what else I need to put :\

Comment: Okay, so you just need a script to tell the application to auto-start on boot?

Comment: @Flabricorn Yes and I would also have no idea where to put it:\

Comment: Okay give me one second to switch to the Linux Machine and I'll put up an answer.

Comment: I don't know what will work since you're in Zorin so try running `gconf -editor` in terminal and what it does.